# Implementing touch based rotation using C# and Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to rotate a Roulette wheel image

this is my xaml

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="roll.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=roll"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


<Grid>



    <TextBlock Text=" One Finger Rotation"
                   FontSize="34"
                   TextAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="64,54,31.791,668"
                   Foreground="Yellow" />

        <Image x:Name="Right"
               Margin="64,170,31.791,141" 
               Source="Roulette.png"

             ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,TranslateInertia"
               ManipulationDelta="Right_ManipulationDelta"
               ImageOpened="Image_Opened" >

            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="RightRotateTransform" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>


</Grid>
```

this is my c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using roll.Resources;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
 using System.Xaml.Object;         


  namespace roll
{


public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }


    private void Image_Opened(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = sender as Image;
        RotateTransform rt = img.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
        rt.CenterX = img.ActualWidth / 2;
        rt.CenterY = img.ActualHeight / 2;
    }

    private void Right_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        var x = this.RightRotateTransform.CenterX - e.Position.X;
        var y = this.RightRotateTransform.CenterY - e.Position.Y;

        double a1 = Math.Atan(y / x);
        double a2 = Math.Atan((e.Delta.Translation.Y - y) / (x - e.Delta.Translation.X));

        this.RightRotateTransform.Angle += a1 - a2;
    }



}
 }
```

In xaml i am geeting error in line ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,TranslateInertia"
it is saying that manipulationmode is not recognized or is not accessible

and in c# getting error in 
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using System.Xaml.Object;
the error says that Xaml does not exist in the namespace Windows.UI

and the other error is in ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs and RotateTransform

Please try to help me
Thanks in advance